# Clicking "flag" on a question that you already flagged as off-topic shows that you also flagged it as a duplicate

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags

I flagged a question as off-topic because it was a "how to get started" question. After flagging the question, I then clicked flag again, and noticed that it had shown that I had not only flagged it as off-topic, but it also had shown that I flagged it as duplicate:

[image: Potential Bug]

I am wondering if this is a bug, or if it is intentionally marked so because this type of question is frequently asked and likely has an answer already. If you look at my remaining flags, you will notice that it didn't consume an extra flag for the second reason, so this isn't a major issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). The message that you have seen clearly says that you had flagged that type of flag and not exactly that flag.

Flagging a question as duplicate, unclear, too broad, offtopic and primarily opinion based are of same type. If you flag again a question as any one of the above, you will be shown the above message.