# Minor "you have already raised this type of flag" bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags

I flagged something as spam, then was only 90% sure I'd done so, so I clicked the flag link again to check. It showed me this:

[image]

I had, of course, only raised the spam flag, not the offensive/abusive/hate flag, so the latter probably shouldn't be saying I did.

---

Ah, this may be a duplicate, I didn't search enough:

- ["You have already raised this flag" Well, not really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188818/you-have-already-raised-this-flag-well-not-really?rq=1)
- [Duplicate flag lists "you have already raised this flag" after flagging as "Unclear what you're asking"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196619/duplicate-flag-lists-you-have-already-raised-this-flag-after-flagging-as-uncl?rq=1)
- [Clicking "flag" on a question that you already flagged as off-topic shows that you also flagged it as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217837/clicking-flag-on-a-question-that-you-already-flagged-as-off-topic-shows-that-y?rq=1)

And if so, it's been around a *while*.

Comment: Well, you have raised that *type* of flag. You can only raise a spam flag, or an offensive flag, but not both on a single post.

Comment: @hichris123: But a spam flag and an offensive flag are **different** types, not the same type. They may be mutually-exclusive, but that does make them the same.

Comment: Not really... see [What are the spam and offensive flags, and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work) (notice "what are the *spam and offensive flags*"). They're lumped under one umbrella.

Comment: @hichris123: Perhaps in an implementation sense. Not in a user sense. "spam" and "offensive" are completely different types of flags to me as a user, at the "external myth" level.

Answer (score 4):

I think this has to do with the severity of the flag and the impact on moderators and the user. I that sense, the flags are 'the same': they are both handled by a moderator with utmost priority. There is no use in raising one of those flags again, since they can't have more priority than the other one. I guess this also prevents one post from flooding the moderator queue.

I do get your argument that the wording could be better. Maybe change the wording to something like this:

> You already flagged this post as spam or offensive. You can't flag raise either of these types again.

Comment: Yeah, that would be better. Separately, as I'm fairly sure I'm not allowed to raise *any* flag while the previous flag is "active" ([according to this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251296/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-you-have-already-raised-this-type-of-flag-message)), I'd expect the third radio button to be disabled as well until the previous flag is resolved (and then to only be able to raise the mod flag or possibly mod or offensive, but not spam).

Comment: I think you can still flag 'spam' if you flagged 'others' or 'NAA'.